# Trying to install a simple kivy app on my phone but got a buildozer last command error message

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyApp().run()
```

Then I got this message:

```
    Can’t exec “aclocal”: No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
    autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
    
    STDERR:
    
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create — dist_name=myapp — bootstrap=sdl2 — requirements=python3,kivy — arch armeabi-v7a — copy-libs — color=always — storage-dir=”/home/js/PycharmProjects/anotherkivytest/.buildozer/android/platform/build” — ndk-api=21
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    # CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = ‘ibus’
    # LS_COLORS = ‘rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:’
    # LESSCLOSE = ‘/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s’
    # LANG = ‘pt_BR.UTF-8’
    # GDM_LANG = ‘pt_BR’
    # DISPLAY = ‘:0’
    # GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = ‘1’
    # COLORTERM = ‘truecolor’
    # XDG_VTNR = ‘7’
    # SSH_AUTH_SOCK = ‘/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh’
    # MANDATORY_PATH = ‘/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path’
    # XDG_SESSION_ID = ‘c2’
    # XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = ‘/var/lib/lightdm-data/js’
    # USER = ‘js’
    # DESKTOP_SESSION = ‘cinnamon’
    # QT4_IM_MODULE = ‘ibus’
    # GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = ‘/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/41d14b2e_8140_419f_8f11_36ec747c2d25’
    # DEFAULTS_PATH = ‘/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path’
    # QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = ‘qt5ct’
    # PWD = ‘/home/js/PycharmProjects/anotherkivytest’
    # HOME = ‘/home/js’
    # SSH_AGENT_PID = ‘1424’
    # QT_ACCESSIBILITY = ‘1’
    # XDG_SESSION_TYPE = ‘x11’
    # XDG_DATA_DIRS = ‘/usr/share/cinnamon:/usr/share/gnome:/home/js/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop’
    # XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = ‘cinnamon’
    # GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = ‘stderr’
    # GTK_MODULES = ‘gail:atk-bridge’
    # TERM = ‘xterm-256color’
    # SHELL = ‘/bin/bash’
    # VTE_VERSION = ‘5202’
    # XDG_SEAT_PATH = ‘/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0’
    # QT_IM_MODULE = ‘ibus’
    # XMODIFIERS = ‘@im=ibus’
    # XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = ‘X-Cinnamon’
    # GPG_AGENT_INFO = ‘/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1’
    # GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ‘:1.228’
    # XDG_SEAT = ‘seat0’
    # SHLVL = ‘1’
    # LANGUAGE = ‘pt_BR:pt:en’
    # GDMSESSION = ‘cinnamon’
    # GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = ‘this-is-deprecated’
    # LOGNAME = ‘js’
    # DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = ‘unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus’
    # XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = ‘/run/user/1000’
    # XAUTHORITY = ‘/home/js/.Xauthority’
    # XDG_SESSION_PATH = ‘/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0’
    # XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = ‘/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg’
    # PATH = ‘/home/js/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin’
    # CINNAMON_VERSION = ‘4.0.8’
    # GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = ‘JS ERROR;JS LOG’
    # SESSION_MANAGER = ‘local/js:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1356,unix/js:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1356’
    # LESSOPEN = ‘| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s’
    # GTK_IM_MODULE = ‘ibus’
    # _ = ‘/usr/local/bin/buildozer’
    # OLDPWD = ‘/home/js/PycharmProjects’
    # PACKAGES_PATH = ‘/home/js/.buildozer/android/packages’
    # ANDROIDSDK = ‘/home/js/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk’
    # ANDROIDNDK = ‘/home/js/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c’
    # ANDROIDAPI = ‘27’
    # ANDROIDMINAPI = ‘21’
    #
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Do you have autoconf installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Verify `$ automake --version`, if none 
$ sudo apt install automake